# Input string not in correct format when converting to int c#

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue I really don't understand!  I'm trying to get the dimensions of picture and then convert that into an int.  I'm getting the sizes (Width_X_Height) and splitting it up into its parts (height and width) but as soon as I try to convert them into int I get the "Input string not in correct format"
I've tried 'Convert.ToInt32' and also 'int.TryParse' both of which I received the above error.
Any help greatly appreciated

```
string[] filenameSplit = fileInDirectory.Split('\\');
string filename = filenameSplit[filenameSplit.Length - 1];
Shell Sh = new Shell();
FolderItem2 FI = (FolderItem2)(Sh.NameSpace(origPath).Items().Item(filename));
string Width_X_Height = (string)(FI.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions"));
var width = "0";
var height = "0";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Width_X_Height))
  {
    string[] widthHeightSplit = Width_X_Height.Split('x');
    width = widthHeightSplit[0].Trim();
    height = widthHeightSplit[1].Trim();
  }
```

Comment: Using the debugger, what is the string value of widthHeightSplit[0] and widthHeightSplit[1] ?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the width & height string to see what is being inputed?

Comment: You also might want to consider the methods in IO.Path to get things like file name.

Comment: from the pic I'm testing the widthHeightSplit[0] is "2065" and widthHeightSplit[1] is "3479".

Comment: Looking in the `Related` section I see lots of similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's a special char in that string and it's not showing in the debugger, but if you put a breakpoint just before converting to int and try `width.ToCharArray()` in the immediate window you'll see a char array with an extra char at the beginning for width and at the end in height.
So the solution is to remove the first or last char (invisible) and then convert or use this method to get just the numbers from a given string

```
private static string NumberFromString(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(input[i]))
            sb.Append(input[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

you can use it like this

```
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(NumberFromString(width));
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(NumberFromString(height));
```

Always check beyond what is visible even through the debugger! :)